# How to add nolock condition in the bookshelf or knex nodejs before fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I am using a bookshelf and wanted to add the default value as WITH(NO LOCK)

**Update: is it possible to achieve this using knex as I have that library installed in my code?**

```
User.forge()
        .fetchAll({withRelated: ['role']})
        .then(function(result) {
            if (result === null)
                res.json({data: []});
            else
                res.json({data: result.toJSON()});
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.json({error: err.message});
        });
```

- I tried adding `User.forge('WITH(NO LOCK)')` but it is not working.
- there is an option to add default values in the model but I don't want to touch the model as it is used in another place in my code so I am looking to add no lock only at one API call.

Comment: what is the database you're using? Is it mssql server?

Comment: `mssql` and `mysql` are two different databases. `WITH (NOLOCK)` is a feature of `mssql`, not `mysql`. Bookshelf doesn't support connecting with `mssql` database. If indeed your database is `mysql` then you don't need to worry about lock on `select`s as mysql doesn't lock the row while doing a select.

Comment: we are using mssql

Comment: Bookshelf is not built for mssql. sequelize could work for your use case, it supports NOLOCK: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/dialect-specific-things/#table-hints---mssql-only

Comment: @AaronDewes can I use knex to achieve this? if you have any references can you please share them?

Comment: @app check this: https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/4509